# Generating random button with colors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, virtual-reality

my friends and I are working on a VR experiment. We currently have code that generates 16 buttons with randomized colors, I would like to have some code that resets the buttons and randomizes the color once again for about 20 times. I'm unsure how to approach the situation. Here is the code we currently have.

```
    public class ButtonManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    Text[] labels;
    Image[] images;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    Color[] colors = new Color[]{
        Color.red,Color.green,Color.yellow,Color.magenta,Color.gray,Color.black
    };
    void Start()
    {
        int chosenOne = Random.Range(0, 16);
        Debug.Log(chosenOne.ToString());
        labels = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>();
        int elemNum = 0;
        foreach (Text txt in labels)
        {
            txt.text = elemNum.ToString();
            elemNum++;
        }
        images = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>();
        elemNum = 0;
        foreach (Image btn in images)
        {
            if (elemNum == chosenOne + 1)
            {
                btn.color = Color.blue;
            }
            else
            {
                btn.color = colors[Random.Range(0, 6)];
            }
            elemNum++;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you separate the buttons creation logic and color setting  logic into two different methods, so you can create buttons only once by calling the `CreateButtons()` method from `Start()`, and also immediately call `SetColors()` from `Start()`, and then you can call `SetColors()` again anytime you want, and reuse the buttons instead of destructing them and re-creating them each time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  public class ButtonManager : MonoBehaviour
  {
    Text[] labels;
    Image[] images;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    Color[] colors = new Color[]{
    Color.red,Color.green,Color.yellow,Color.magenta,Color.gray,Color.black
    };
    void Start()
    {
    labels = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>();
    foreach (Text txt in labels)
    {
        txt.text = elemNum.ToString();
        elemNum++;
    }
    images = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>();
    foreach (Image btn in images)
    {
       btn.color = colors[Random.Range(0, colors.Length)];
    }
   }

   // Update is called once per frame
   void Update()
   {
    
   }
}
```